# How to hide positionWigdet when keyboard is open at indexedStack Flutter

Tags: flutter

I used IndexedStack in my main.dart, I am using 3 different pages here. Like x.dart, y.dart, z.dart.

I have such a banner on page X. Bottom 0 is coming. Appears when the keyboard is on. I want to hide this when the keyboard is open. But since indexedstack is in main.dart, I cannot control keyboard open / not on x.dart page.

How can I hide this while the keyboard is on? I would appreciate it if you could help.

Banner code here.

```
  return Positioned(
            width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
            height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
            child: Align(
              child: Container(
                width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
                height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: child,
              ),
            ));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of [flutter_keyboard_visibility](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_keyboard_visibility) package:

- Import package in your pubspec.yaml.
- Run `flutter pub get`.
- In your **main.dart** code wrap your indexed stack with `KeyboardVisibilityBuilder` and use it to hide your `Positioned` X widget like so:

```
import 'package:flutter_keyboard_visibility/flutter_keyboard_visibility.dart';

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return KeyboardVisibilityBuilder(
    builder: (context, isKeyboardVisible) {
      return IndexedStack(
               index: 1,
               children: <Widget>[
                 if(!isKeyboardVisible) XWidget(),
                 YWidget(),
                 ZWidget(),
                 ],
               )
             }
          );
```

If you need to hide only part of Positioned widget, just pass `isKeyboardVisible` to your X widget and conditionally hide your banner same way.